# Uploading Excel File in MVC using angularjs. HttpPostedFileBase is empty

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, excel, file-upload

I am trying to upload an excel file in mvc using angular js. Following is my view code:

```
    <div class="browsebtn" ng-controller = "serviceablectrlr"><input type="file" id="dataFile" name="uploadFile" data-max-size="2097152" accept=".xls, .xlsx" onclick="$('#fileError').hide();" /> 
</div>
<input id="btnUploadExcel" type="button" value="Upload" ng-click="UploadConfirmation()" class="btn  btn-yellow" />
```

Following is my controller Code :

```
var app = angular.module('ProductCatalog');

app.controller('serviceablectrlr', function ($scope, $http) {

    var apiURL = $("#ProductCatalogApiUrl").val();
    var ClearFile = function () {
            $("#dataFile").val('');
        }


// pass file object and url to this method
$scope.UploadConfirmation = function () {
    alert("sana");
    var formData = new FormData();
    var totalFiles = document.getElementById("dataFile").files.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
        var file = document.getElementById("dataFile").files[i];
        var ext = file.name.split(".")[1];
        if ((ext == "xls" || ext == "xlsx") && file.size < (Math.pow(1024, 3) * 2)) {
            formData.append("dataFile", file);

            $http({

                method: 'POST',
                url: apiURL + "/BulkInsertion",
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined},
                transformRequest: angular.identity

            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                if (response.data.ResponseData == 'Success') {
                    showToastrMessage('success', 'Offer saved successfully!');
                    $scope.data = {};
                }
                else {
                    alert('In error');
                    showToastrMessage('error', response.data.ResponseData);
                }
            },
            function errorCallback(response) {
            });

        }
        else {

        }
    }

}
});
```

And following is my MVC Controller code:

```
   public ResponseModel Post(
            HttpPostedFileBase dataFile
            )
        { }
```

The problem i am facing is that the HttpPostedFileBase is null even though i am sending the correct parameters.

I have referred to the following question which is exactly my problem other than I am working on excel file uploading.

[HttpPostedFileBase is null when uploading files with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569480/httppostedfilebase-is-null-when-uploading-files-with-angular)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write following code in your cshtml view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActioName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{         
       <div>
            <input type="file" name="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="OK" class="button" />
        </div>       
}
```

In MVC controller

```
[HttpPost]
      public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase myFile)
      {
        //Validate the fileType

        // Verify that the user selected a file
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
        //do something here...
        }
      }
```

In cae you want to do with angular js then use following code to post file

```
// pass file object and url to this method
this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file,  uploadUrl) { 
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: uploadUrl,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: function() {
            var formData = new FormData();
            if(file){
               formData.append("myFile", file); 
            }
            return formData;
        }
    })
}
```

Add this in `WebApiConfig.Register()`:

```
this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));
```

Comment: @Sana, can you please check in request object -> Request.Files; just try to get the value of "Request.Files" in post method

Comment: Request.Files yielded no results it says while debugging it

Comment: @Sana, oh i got it.If you are truing to upload using angular then please change declaration of your controller method. parameter name should be "myFile" instead of file. It should work. I updated my answer

Comment: it is giving me this error now No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'HttpPostedFileBase' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.

Comment: @Sana I guess you need to add supported media type. i updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for bearing up with me. It is working now. Thanks a ton :)