# MaxJsonLength exception in ASP.NET MVC AngularJS during JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have implemented image upload page using angularJS.

html binding part and anguler controller part working fine.but problem is when I pass object with uploaded images(64 base string) to server side using Ajax call.
it'll give a error something like "**Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.....**"

I have tried adding

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
  </webServices>
</scripting>
```

but it doesn't work.

this is my angular service below,

*In my angular service "purchaseOrder" is object include with OrderId,Price,ImageUploaded (image as 64 base string)*

```
'use strict';
appForm.factory('CheckoutService', function ($http) {
 function CompleteCheckout(purchaseOrder) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Checkout/CompleteCheckout',
        data: { "objPurchaseOrder": purchaseOrder }
    }).then(function (results) {
        return results.data;
    })
};
return {
      GetCartItems:GetCartItems
}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first problem is with your approach. You should not upload a file in base64. If you do this then it is going to impact your performance and network usage. Actually when you convert a file in base64 then file size automatically increases to 33%. So if you have a file of 10MB then it will be increase to 13MB.

So instead of uploading file content like this, use multipart implementation. I have give answer about multipart file upload. You can check it here [Uploading Excel File in MVC using angularjs. HttpPostedFileBase is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45504937/uploading-excel-file-in-mvc-using-angularjs-httppostedfilebase-is-empty/45540350#45540350)